# C# client object model to connect to SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, client-object-model

I am trying to connect to SharePoint online site using SharePointOnlinecredentials.
I am just passing the user ID and the password( secure string form) and just retrieveing the web.Title.  the code when i run on my local system is running fine without any issues and I can see the web title on the console as it is dotnet console application.

But when I am trying to run the application from another server, I am receiving the below error.

System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected
party did not properly respond after a period of time,
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond (host IP and port here) at
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at
System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.GetRequestStream()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Answer (score 1):

The error shows there is connection error between the server and SharePoint online, confirm the server has internet access first.

If you could access SharePoint online from the server directly, try to use Fiddler to troubleshoot the console app request.